# Can I configure ghostdoc to generate javadoc type of comment header for c++ codes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ghostdoc

Is there anyway to configure ghostdoc to generate javadoc type comment head for c++ classes and function?

I am using GhostDoc inside visual studio and I like to generate javadoc type of comments, but ghostdoc generate xml type of comments.

Is there anyway that I can configure ghosdoc to generate javadoc type of comment header??

Is there any other free software that I can use it inside visual studio 2013/2015 to do generate javadoc type of comments header for c++ code?

Comment: Which is the question? Which tool to user (rather vague questio) or how to invoke it from Visual studio?

Comment: The question is : can I configure ghostdoc to generate javadoc type of comment header for c++ codes? if yes, how?

Comment: Ah, ok. The only anser I have for you is that any such command can be configured in the 'build events' section of 'Configuration properties'. But I don'w know GhostDoc

Comment: You can reconfigure GhostDoc templates for JavaDoc format in the Pro version.